# linking static libraries with libtool

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries, libtool

How to link a static library `(.a)` with libtool?

I am creating a apache module (`mod_shib_22.so`) which is using three RSA library `libcertc.a` , `libcertcsp.a` and `libbsafe.a`
I am linking these libraries with `-lcertc -lcertcsp -lbafe` but while loading the module I am getting "symbol undefined" errors:

```
./apachectl -k stop httpd: Syntax error on line 426 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load /usr/local/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_22.so into server:  /usr/local/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_22.so: undefined symbol: T_GetDynamicList
```

I am using these lines in Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS = -L../../libraries/Crypto-C-6.4.0.3/lib/linux_lsb30_x86_64 -L../../libraries/Cert-C-2.9.0.0/lib/LinuxLSB30_x86_64/release_mt
LIBOBJS = 
LIBS = -lxerces-c -L/usr/local/lib64 -llog4shib -lnsl -lcertc -lcertcsp -lbsafe -ldl
```

Comment: Others libraries are getting linked as there are shared.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290771/creating-static-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Linking a DSO (an Apache module in this case) with a static library isn't guaranteed to work, and probably won't work depending on how the objects in the static library are built. Usually objects in static libraries are not built with [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) enabled, but DSOs *require* position independent code.

Comment: I have other apache module which is getting linked properly using same static libraries  but its not using libtool.
Is libtool makes any Difference?

Comment: You'll need to post the output of libtool when it links `mod_shib_22.so`.

Comment: ./apachectl -k stop
httpd: Syntax error on line 426 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/local/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_22.so into server: /usr/local/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_22.so: undefined symbol: T_GetDynamicList
I am using these lines in Makefile
LDFLAGS = -L../../libraries/Crypto-C-6.4.0.3/lib/linux_lsb30_x86_64  -L../../libraries/Cert-C-2.9.0.0/lib/LinuxLSB30_x86_64/release_mt
LIBOBJS =
LIBS =  -lxerces-c -L/usr/local/lib64 -llog4shib -lnsl -lcertc -lcertcsp -lbsafe -ldl